# How to block access to group of users with directory roles

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

In my tenant, I want to restrict access to few users to my application even they have directory admin roles.

I'm thinking of implementing conditional access policy. I have premium p2 license, is this sufficient to work with conditional access?

How to create policy to restrict access to admins? Any help is appreciated

Comment: Azure AD had a feature to [allow specific users](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-restrict-your-app-to-a-set-of-users) to access the application, but admin account has the permission to edit the policy...

Comment: Admin in the sense Application admins

Comment: Do they have permissions to edit conditional policy?

Comment: In Azure AD, there's a role named golble admin, it cal edit any policy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got below results:***

I have created one Azure AD group named **`AppAdminCA`** by adding ***'Application Admin'*** role to that group like below:

[image]

This means every user in that group has ***'Application Admin'*** role. **Note** that, Application Admin role don't have access to modify conditional access policies.

To **restrict** access for these users to a specific application, you can create *"Conditional access policy"* like below:

***Go to Azure Portal -> Azure Active Directory -> Security -> Conditional Access -> Policies -> New policy***

[image]

In **`Users`** field, you can select ***either*** Users with **Directory role** or the above created **group** like below:

[image]

In **`Cloud apps`** field, select that ***particular application*** to which you want to block access as below:

[image]

In **`Access controls`** field, select ***Block access*** and click on **Create** by enabling the policy:

[image]

You can find the created **conditional policy** here:

[image]

Comment: That's what I found in the end. Anyway, thanks for the help